# How can I use Adobe Connect Add-in on Ubuntu

Tags: wine, flash, 17.04

I use Adobe Connect to host online meetings. For some features to work I need to use a special version of flash designed for that product called Adobe Connect Add-in, which integrates into the web browser. However, there is no Add-in for Linux. Would it possible to install this Add-in on Chrome or Firefox through Wine?